# Bootstrap navbar doesn't collapse when visit from mobile device, works fine when I shrink desktop browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an index.html and require bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js.When I shrink desktop browser on my desktop, the navbar collapses properly. When I visit the site on my mobile device,everything is responsive EXCEPT the navbar,it doesn't collapse
here is my code
in head

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Sylhet International University</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">


       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loaders.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.akordeon.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

in body

```
    <!--Navigation Starts-->
<div class="navigation">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navigation_bar scroll_border navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container ">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ADMISSION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">COURSES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<!--Navigation Ends-->
```

in footer

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Add this script
bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `bootstrap.min.js` in your scripts:

```
<script src="path/to/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also double String around js/bootstrap.min.js""
Do add jquery min 2.1 before bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to insert : bootstrap.min.js

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also double String around  js/bootstrap.min.js""

Answer (score 0):

Well, You inserted required files(jquery.min.js, bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js).

I test your body code in bootstrap template. That's right. It works in Desktop and Mobile devices correctly.

I think some other files Caused this problem. First Remove other .CSS and .JS files to check it, and then You can find problem better.